# An object in the Automapper is returning null

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to work on a sample example to map  CustomerViewItem(Source) and Customer(Destination).

Here is the Source Entities that I am trying to map

```
public class CustomerViewItem
{
    public CompanyViewItem companyViewItem { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyEmployees { get; set; }
    public string CompanyType { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfOrders { get; set; }
    public bool VIP { get; set; }
} 

public class Customer
{
    public Company company { get; set; }        
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int CompanyEmployees { get; set; }
    public string CompanyType { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfOrders { get; set; }
    public bool VIP { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string TempAddress { get; set; }
    public string PermAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Employees { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }

}

public class CompanyViewItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Employees { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
}
```

Now for the CustomerViewItem Entity, I have added some sample values. Since the CompanyViewItem in the CustomerViewItem is a class which in turn had a class, I have added the values in this way

```
companyViewItem = new CompanyViewItem() { address = new Address { PermAddress = "pAdd", TempAddress = "tAdd" }, Employees = 15, Name = "name", Type = "abc" }
```

Now here is my AutoMapper code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerViewItem, Customer>();
CustomerViewItem customerViewItem = GetCustomerViewItemFromDB();
Customer customer = Mapper.Map<CustomerViewItem,Customer>customerViewItem);
```

Everything is running fine but, only company in returning null.
I have tried in vice versa too, the same is returning  null.
Could some one help me out with this?

Comment: Are you using `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` ? This *should* catch discrepancies

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but I would seriously recommend checking out `duck typing` and `Clay` in particular. It does essentially what `Automapper` does under the hood (`dynamic proxy`-like stuff) but you get to skip all this mapping madness. Performance may be slighly slower or faster, it depends on your object graph depth and size (~1million records gonna be non performant, just to let you know).

Comment: @Invent-Animate: I used that, it is throwing an exception which says "The following one properties on Customer are not mapped: Company Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, or rename the property on CustomerViewItem"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing mapping configuration between `CompanyViewItem` and `Company`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyViewItem, Company>();
```

Your mapping code should be something like:

```
// Setup
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerViewItem, Customer>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.company, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.companyViewItem));
Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyViewItem, Company>();

CustomerViewItem customerViewItem = GetCustomerViewItemFromDB();

// Mapping
Customer customer = Mapper.Map<CustomerViewItem,Customer>(customerViewItem);
```

Comment: Hi. I changed the code as you said. But, the company is still returning null don't know why.

Comment: Refer to my updated answer. Since `company` and `companyViewItem` have different names you need to define explicit mapping for them.

Comment: Hi. I made some changes again.I have replaced Address property with "public AddressViewItem addressViewItem { get; set; }" in 'CompanyViewItem' class. The Mapper code is Same as u mentioned above. Now address is returning null.  I have changed the mapper code like this "Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyViewItem, Company>().ForMember(t => t.address, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.addressViewItem));" but this is giving "Trying to map AutoMapperDemo.CustomerViewItem to AutoMapperDemo.Customer." exception. Is there anything missing which I need to modify the code?

Comment: I figured out the mistake. This is the modified mapper code. "Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyViewItem, Company>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.address, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.addressViewItem));

            Mapper.CreateMap<AddressViewItem, Address>();" Thanks all!

Comment: Shouldn't Automapper just ignore the property that is not mapped and map the other properties? I have used this approach before to map one object to multiple objects with different mapping configurations. Automapper just ignored the dissimilar properties and mapped others. But mine is also returning null object now :(

Answer (score 7):

If you were getting `mapper.map()` returning null in your unit tests, make sure you do **not** mock the automapper dependency to whatever service you are testing, but instead use the real thing.